# Ensuring two columns only contain valid results from same subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
id   symbol_01   symbol_02
1    abc         xyz
2    kjh         okd
3    que         qid
```

I need a query that ensures symbol_01 and symbol_02 are both contained in a list of valid symbols. In other words I would needs something like this:

```
select * 
from mytable
where symbol_01 in (
    select valid_symbols 
    from somewhere)
and symbol_02 in (
    select valid_symbols 
    from somewhere)
```

The above example would work correctly, but the subquery used to determine the list of valid symbols is identical both times and is quite large. It would be very innefficient to run it twice like in the example.

Is there a way to do this without duplicating two identical sub queries?

Comment: if your rate of inserts are less,can you  add a column which says valid or not

Comment: Unfortunately what classifies as 'valid symbols' is determined by end users through a web interface. So the subquery selects the valid symbols based on the user requirements. So inserting extra columns wouldn't really be feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try use a CTE like;

```
WITH ValidSymbols AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT valid_symbol
    FROM somewhere
)
SELECT mt.* 
FROM MyTable mt
INNER JOIN ValidSymbols v1
    ON mt.symbol_01 = v1.valid_symbol
INNER JOIN ValidSymbols v2
    ON mt.symbol_02 = v2.valid_symbol
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
select *
from mytable t1
where 2 = (select count(distinct symbol)
           from valid_symbols vs
           where vs.symbol in (t1.symbol_01, t1.symbol_02));
```

This assumes that the valid symbols are stored in a table `valid_symbols` that has a column named `symbol`. The query would also benefit from an index on `valid_symbols.symbol`

Comment: What if symbol_01 = symbol_02? Then the distinct count is 1. (OK, they are never the same in the sample data provided, but if they could be.)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: if that can happen, then you would use `count(symbol)` or simply `count(*)` instead

Answer (score 1):

From a performance perspective, your query is the right way to do this.  I would write it as:

```
select * 
from mytable t
where exists (select 1 
              from valid_symbols vs
              where t.symbol_01 = vs.valid_symbol
             ) and
      exists (select 1 
              from valid_symbols vs
              where t.symbol_02 = vs.valid_symbol
             ) ;
```

The important component is that you need an index on `valid_symbols(valid_symbol)`.  With this index, the lookup should be pretty fast.  Appropriate indexes can even work if `valid_symbols` is a view, although the effect depends on the complexity of the view.

You seem to have a situation where you have two foreign key relationships.  If you explicitly declare these relationships, then the database will enforce that the columns in your table match the valid symbols.